# Django TypeError when related model is None

Tags: python, django, view, typeerror, iterable

I'm trying to generate a contract in .pdf

Not every contract has a 'fiador' (guarantor), so I'm getting this error when I try to generate a contract without one.

'Contrato' (Contract) is a Model. 'Fiador' (guarantor) is another.

```
class Fiador(PersonAttr):

    contrato = models.ForeignKey('Contrato',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='fiador')
```

I made a function to get the correct article (in portuguese, 'a' is for females and 'o' for males).

```
def artigo_fiador(pk):
    
    contrato = get_object_or_404(Contrato, pk=pk)

    masculino = []
    feminino = []
    
    if hasattr(contrato, 'fiador'):

        [masculino.append(1) for f in contrato.fiador.all() if f.genero == 'Masculino']
        [feminino.append(1) for f in contrato.fiador.all() if f.genero == 'Feminino']

    

        if len(contrato.fiador.all()) > 1:
            if len(masculino) < 1:
                artigo_fiador = 'as'
                genero_fiador = 'as'
                return artigo_fiador, genero_fiador
            else:
                artigo_fiador = 'os'
                genero_fiador = 'es'
                
                return artigo_fiador, genero_fiador    

        else:
            for fiador in contrato.fiador.all():
                if fiador.genero == 'Feminino':
                    artigo_fiador = 'a'
                    genero_fiador = 'a'
                    return artigo_fiador, genero_fiador
                else:
                    artigo_fiador = 'o'
                    genero_fiador = ''
                    return artigo_fiador, genero_fiador
```

And in my views, I'm trying to pass the function like this:

```
from .logic import artigos as at

class Contract(view):
[...]
    artigo_fiador, genero_fiador = at.artigo_fiador(pk)

data = {

    'artigo_fiador': artigo_fiador,
    'genero_fiador': genero_fiador,
```

I'm using xhtml2pdf.

The error i'm getting is the following:

```
TypeError at /contrato/16/contrato_p
cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

and the line that triggered the error:

```
 259.       artigo_fiador, genero_fiador = at.artigo_fiador(pk)
```

I can understand that fiador, in this case, is None. How can I avoid type errors in this case?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, give us the line that triggered the error.

Comment: Sorry. It's this one:         artigo_fiador, genero_fiador = at.artigo_fiador(pk) 

Thanks for noticing this. I already eddited my question.